# How to only dissect one attribute of a Zigbee Cluster Library frame in a Wireshark Lua dissector

Tags: lua, zigbee, wireshark-dissector

this is my first time asking and I am new to Lua, so please correct me if I am doing something wrong

**General Problem:**

I want to write a Lua dissector for wireshark that only dissects one attribute of a given Zigbee Cluster Library frame (see screenshot).

[image: Wireshark example frame with attribute]

Now I have got many problems and solutions for them that don't work.

**Problem 1 - Adding the dissector (at the right spot?):**

for testing purposes I added my dissector to the DissectorTable with the name **"wpan.panid"** for my given PANID with the value of "0x9dbd". This works, but only for the given PANID and way too "low level", because I want to only change one attribute in a deeper layer.

**Question 1:**
So how do I get the dissector to always get called, no matter which PANID and how do I "anchor" (for lack of better wording) it only for my attribute **"zbee_zcl.attr.id"**

**Problem 2 - Letting the "official" wireshark dissectors do its work and then just alter their result**

My thought was, that I could call the wireshark dissectors **"zbee_nwk"**, **"zbee_aps"** and **"zbee_zcl"** for the three layers and just alter the one attribute I want to dissect. But when I get the **"zbee_nwk"** dissector and call the call method on it with the exact same information that my dissector got, nothing happens and the tree just stays the same (see next screenshot).

[image: My Wireshark Console. For code, see below]

```
alreadyCalled = false

networkDissector = Dissector.get("zbee_nwk")
applicationSupportDissector = Dissector.get("zbee_aps")
clusterLibraryDissector = Dissector.get("zbee_zcl")

local myProtoField = ProtoField.new("zbee_zcl.attr.id", "zzbee_zcl.attr.id", ftypes.UINT16)
function myFunction(treeViewBuffer, packetInfo, tree)
    if(alreadyCalled == false) then
        print(tostring(treeViewBuffer) .. " / " .. tostring(packetInfo) .. " / " .. tostring(tree))
        print("Nr. of changed stuff: " .. networkDissector:call(treeViewBuffer, packetInfo, tree))
        print(tostring(treeViewBuffer) .. " / " .. tostring(packetInfo) .. " / " .. tostring(tree))
        alreadyCalled = true
    end
end

myProtocol = Proto("MYZIGBEE", "myZigbee")
myProtocol.dissector = myFunction
DissectorTable.get("wpan.panid"):add(0x9dbd, myProtocol)
```

**Questions 2:**

- Why doesn't the called dissector alter the tree it is given?
- Am I calling the call method wrong?
- could it be, because the payload is encrypted and I just added the key in the Wireshark application?

**TLDR:**
How would someone with knowledge and experience dissect the attribute and only the attribute shown in the first screenshot and let the "official" wireshark dissectors do the rest.

**Example for dissection:**
Attribute: 0x0400 -> Attribute: Temperature (0x0400)

**FROM ACCEPTED ANSWER: (By no means perfect. Loop could probably be made much more efficient)**

```
function zbee_postDissector.dissector(tvbuf, pinfo, tree)

local attr_id_ex = {attr_id()}
i = 1
myValue = attr_id_ex[i]

if myValue == nil then
    return
end

pinfo.cols.protocol:set("zbee_post")

local attr_id_tvbr = attr_id_ex.range
local zbee_post_tree = tree:add(zbee_postDissector, attr_id_tvbr)

while myValue ~= nil do
    zbee_post_tree:add(pf.attr_id, myValue.range, myValue.value)
    
    i = i + 1
    myValue = attr_id_ex[i]
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it's not possible to modify an existing tree item.  But what you can do is write a Lua postdissector that adds a new treeitem that is a modification of the existing tree item.  For example:

```
local zbee_post = Proto("zbee_post", "zbee_post dissector")

-- The table of attribute IDs you care about.
local attr_id_vals = {
    [0x0001] =  "Foo",
    [0x0004] = "Temperature"
}

local pf = {
    attr_id = ProtoField.uint16("zbee_post.attr.id", "Attribute", base.HEX, attr_id_vals)
}
zbee_post.fields = pf

local attr_id = Field.new("zbee_zcl.attr.id")

function zbee_post.dissector(tvbuf, pinfo, tree)

    local attr_id_ex = attr_id()
    if attr_id_ex == nil then
        return
    end

    pinfo.cols.protocol:set("zbee_post")

    local attr_id_tvbr = attr_id_ex.range
    local zbee_post_tree = tree:add(zbee_post, attr_id_tvbr)

    zbee_post_tree:add(pf.attr_id, attr_id_tvbr, attr_id_ex.value)
end

register_postdissector(zbee_post)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didnt't know about post-dissectors so this was very helpful.

For anyone with the same problem and frames with more than one Attribute, see the edited Question.